# How to split a file based on column then drop that column in awk or bash

Tags: bash, text, awk

I have the following tab-separated data in a `.txt` file:

```
ID1 1.1
ID2 1.1
ID3 1.1
ID4 1.1
ID5 1.1
ID6 1.1.1
ID7 1.1.1
ID8 1.1.1
ID9 1.1.1
ID10 1.1.1
```

I want to split this file into separate files based on the second column, but I also want to drop that same column, so that I'm just left with the ID numbers in each file.

I can split the file like this: `awk '{print>$2}' file.txt`. But I can't do the second part where I'm just left with the IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
awk -F$'\t' '{print $1>$2}' file.txt
```

You tell `awk` that the field separator is a tab. Then you write the first field to a file called like the second field.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Using close should save us from error of "too many files opened one"

```
awk '{print $1 >> ($2);close($2)}'  Input_file
```

In case you Input_file is TAB delimited then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $1 >> ($2);close($2)}' Input_file
```

Comment: These commands just save the first row (first ID), sorry. The above answer by Poshi works well.

Comment: @Gary Napier, I fixed that issue please check once and let me know.